# Отсортировать данные через LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

В общем у меня есть список нужно обработать данные и получить на выходе такие данные, только есть условие, нужно сделать через Linq.
Данные могут быть записаны хаотично, то есть записей с null может и не быть, картинка это просто пример логики

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Какой тип на входе (`Dictionary<?,?>`) и какой тип должен быть на выходе?

Comment: string,string на входе и выходе

Comment: А что делать с таким вводом: `[1, null], [5, id], [100, null]`? И сортировка первой компоненты должна быть числовой (1 < 5 < 100) или строковой ("1" < "100" < "5")?

Comment: строковой ввод все время идет

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну, если я правильно понял, то можно с помощью LINQ написать так:

```
var input = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    {"1", "10"},
    {"2", "20"},
    {"3", "30"},
    {"4", "40"},
    {"5", null},
    {"7", null},
    {"8", "50"}
};
//преобразуем ключи в int
var intKeys = input
    .Select(item => new {Key = int.Parse(item.Key), item.Value})
    .ToList();
var notNulls = intKeys
    //отфильтровываем нули
    .Where(item => item.Value != null)
    //сортируем
    .OrderBy(item => item.Key)
    .ToList();
var result = notNulls
    //сливаем список с самим собой чтобы получить пары (текущий, следующий)
    .Zip(notNulls
            //сдвигаем на 1
            .Skip(1)
            //добавляем фиктивный элемент максимум+1 в конце, чтобы у всех элементов была пара
            .Concat(Enumerable.Repeat(new {Key = intKeys.Max(i => i.Key) + 1, Value = ""}, 1)),
        //собираем диапазон
        (current, next) => new
        {
            //если есть промежуток со следующим, то составляем диапазон [текущий;следующий-1]
            //если нет, то в качестве ключа текущий элемент
            Key = current.Key + 1 == next.Key ? $"{current.Key}" : $"{current.Key}-{next.Key - 1}",
            current.Value
        }
    );
//ToDictionary или ToLookup по вкусу
foreach (var v in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{v.Key}, {v.Value}");
}
```

Я бы вторую часть (слияние текущего элемента со следующим) написал бы через цикл, возможно, так код был бы более понятен.

Comment: спасибо буду пробовать

Comment: а если после [8,50] идет [9,null] то оно не записывает [8-9,50]

Comment: @Colibri да, не записывает. Вот поэтому важно расписывать требования поподробнее в вопросе. Кстати, что нужно делать если в начале будет [1,null]? И что если отсчет начнется с 2, а элемент с 1 не будет?

Comment: [1,null] не может быть так что 1 элемент всегда со значением, это по условию так

Comment: и 1 элемент всегда есть

Comment: @Colibri поправил код, чтобы максимум получался из оригинального словаря, а не из отфильтрованного списка.

Comment: сейчас попробую

Comment: все работает корректно, спасибо огромное)

Answer (score 2):

> нужно сделать через Linq

Не нужно.
Каждому инструменту - своё предназначение.
В данном случае цели можно достичь за один проход по коллекции.
Конечно, с десятком элементов это не важно. Но на больших объёмах может быть критично.

```
var items = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
{
    new("1", "10"),
    new("2", "20"),
    new("3", "30"),
    new("4", "40"),
    new("5", null),
    new("7", null),
    new("8", "50"),
    new("9", null)
};

var result = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++)
{
    if (items[i].Value != null)
    {
        int j = i + 1;
        if (j < items.Count && items[j].Value == null)
        {
            while (j < items.Count && items[j].Value == null)
            {
                j++;
            }

            string key = items[i].Key + "-" + items[j - 1].Key;
            result.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key, items[i].Value));
            i = j - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            result.Add(items[i]);
        }
    }
}

foreach (var item in result)
    Console.WriteLine(item);
```

Если вместо индексируемого списка имеется какая-либо другая коллекция, думаю, не составит труда преобразовать её: `.OrderBy(...).ToList()`. Конечно, это добавит накладные расходы. Поэтому стоит изначально подумать о правильном выборе подходящей коллекции.

Comment: так данный метод должен это делать это с огромным количеством данных, это просто пример был